# How can I disable or shorten cut sequences in FIFA 13?

Tags: fifa-13

One thing I've noticed in FIFA 13 is that the duration of cut sequences when you change a player is really long. This is really getting on my nerves. I don't want to watch a guy holding up the numbers or player walking around for 5 or 6 seconds, especially in multiplayer. **Is there a way to configure the duration of these sequences, or turn them off entirely?** I haven't found any settings for this yet, but maybe there's some sort of hack to disable them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, there are other things in FIFA 12 that got a lot more annoying in 13, like the news pop-ups in career mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly (although annoying) you can't , they need these long cut scenes to load the player models in subs etc.. Or else it would just be a black screen for a few seconds. Frustrating I know.. I found if you make 3 subs at a time , it usually just loads for a second without showing the cut scene.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, although it takes like two seconds on my box to start a game, where it loads the stadium, the players and all the textures. FIFA really isn't heavy. Look at stuff like World of Warcraft instances or even cities. There's far more things to load and that is fast as hell on a decent machine. I feel this is just really annoying. But it looks like we can't do anything about it. Thanks a lot for your thoughts!